# How to get replica of line drawn using CGContextAddLineToPoint to get effects like Amizograph app?

Tags: ios, drawing

I am working on an application similar to Amaziograph also known as kaleidoscope or mandala.

Here is what I have done till now.

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:_imageDrawing];

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_imageDrawing.frame.size);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[_imageDrawing.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _imageDrawing.frame.size.width, _imageDrawing.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, red, green, blue, alpha);
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);

// Original track
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, location.x, location.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentLocation.x, currentLocation.y);

// Same x position different y
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, location.x, self.imageDrawing.frame.size.height - location.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentLocation.x, self.imageDrawing.frame.size.height - currentLocation.y);

// Same y position different x
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx , self.imageDrawing.frame.size.width - location.x,location.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, self.imageDrawing.frame.size.width - currentLocation.x, currentLocation.y);

// different y position different x
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx , self.imageDrawing.frame.size.width - location.x,self.imageDrawing.frame.size.height - location.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, self.imageDrawing.frame.size.width - currentLocation.x, self.imageDrawing.frame.size.height - currentLocation.y);

CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
_imageDrawing.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

location = currentLocation;enter image description here
```

Is there any SDK available to develop the application like Amizograph?

Here is the link for this app or How can I implement this manually?

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amaziograph/id586076398?ls=1&mt=8
http://www.amaziograph.com/

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Ranjan: Its look like a symmetric photo creation and editing tool. Try to search some sdk.

Comment: Hey Have you found any solution because this thing also bothering me. If you have any solution, could you please share it?